# Dota2 cannot display on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: nvidia, 16.04, graphics, opengl, nvidia-geforce

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 64 bit, Graphic card GeForce 210/PCIe/SSE2.
The game can launch, I can hear the sound, clickable but game screen just like this:

[image]

Comment: You don't seem to meet the minimum specs with that GPU, minimum is gtx 8600 and that is a faster card than yours. That card is not for gaming. http://dev.dota2.com/showthread.php?t=96878

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem with Geforce 210 and Nvidia driver v304.

Try this in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia-*
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-340
```

then reboot.